# Constructor taking shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef, shared-ptr, make-shared

I have situation like this

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y)
    {
    }
    int x, y;
};

class Bar
{
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<const Foo>  ConstFooPtr;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Foo>        FooPtr;

    Bar(int index = 0, FooPtr ptr = FooPtr()) : index_(index), ptr_(ptr)
    {
    }

private:
    ConstFooPtr ptr_;
    int index_;
};
```

I want to produce Bar and 2 methods comes to my mind

```
Bar::FooPtr ptr(new Foo(1, 2)); //1

auto ptr2 = std::make_shared<Bar::FooPtr::element_type>(42, 13); //2

auto bar = Bar(0, ptr);
```

The first one is pretty general, because if I will change the type of `FooPtr` perhaps I will not have to chage this code. But it uses `new` which is bad I guess.

Second doesn't use `new`, but it assumes that it is `shared_ptr` which is not general also.

Is there any method to make it work and be general? Or maybe I should never take some ptrs in constructor?

(I store `ptr` to `const Foo` because I will make copies of `Bar` and change `index_`, but `data` in `ptr_` will be the same - You can assume that `Foo` is something big with some containers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just roll your own version of `make_shared` and put it as a static member of `Bar`:

```
template<typename... Args>
static FooPtr make_shared_foo(Args... args)
{
    return ::std::make_shared<Foo>(::std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

This way you can make you pointer like so:

```
auto ptr3 = Bar::make_shared_foo(3,14159);
```

Of course, nothing prevents you from taking this to its ultimate version:

```
Bar(int index = 0) : index_(index), ptr_(FooPtr())
{ }

template<typename... Args>
Bar(int index, Args... args)
    : index_(index)
    , ptr_(new Foo(::std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{ }
```

Which just allows you to pass your arguments to the constructor to `Bar` which will then forward them to create a pointer to `Foo` for its own consumption.